# Mixing if ..; with { command-grouping} and [[ test ]] and logical operators

Tags: bash, shell-script, test

**Edit**: I've tried again and now it works fine in `bash`. I don't know what changed. My editor (VS Code with Bash IDE extension) still gives me a `failed to parse` error, but the script runs properly. Should I delete the question?

**Original question**

My script currently does this:

```
if cmd1; then
  echo Success
else
  if [[ "$x" == "z" ]] && cmd2; then
    echo Success
  else
    echo Failure
  fi
fi
```

I've been trying to shorten in it to a 'one-liner' but `bash` chokes on a statement like this:

```
if cmd1 || { [[ "$x" = "z" ]] && cmd2; }; then
   echo Success
else
   echo Failure
fi
```

I think the `{ grouping }` is necessary because otherwise the `&& cmd` will always be executed. How can I fix this?

Comment: Works for me on Bash 3.2 through 5.0-alpha with `cmd1() { false; }; cmd2() { true; }; x=z; if cmd1 || { [[ "$x" = "z" ]] && cmd2; }; then echo Success; fi`, where the condition part was directly copied from the above.

Comment: One gotcha with `{ .. }` is that you need the final semicolon, and spaces around the braces, but you have all of those in your code...

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @don_crissti it's not valid it's missing #! so we don't know the intended interpreter. also there is a missing "fi"

Comment: It shouldn't matter what shell that runs in. `[[ .. ]]` is obviously non-standard, but it wouldn't work in the first script either, and it should give a fairly obvious error message.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a subshell to group it:

```
if cmd1 || ( [[ "$x" == 'z' ]] && cmd2 ); then
  ...
else
  ...
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

It works fine:

```
cmd1() { return 1; }
cmd2() { return 0; }
x=z
if cmd1 || { [[ "$x" = "z" ]] && cmd2; }; then
   echo Success
else
   echo Failure
fi
```

```
Success
```

Are you sure you're not running this code in `sh`? That will give you something like

```
sh: 4: [[: not found
```

Comment: @glennjackman - this is weird! it started working for me too.. My editor (VS Code with the Bash IDE extension still gives me a parsing error, and previously when I tried it in `bash` directly it didn't work. Should I delete the question?

Comment: Probably. As it stands, there are grounds for closure: "Questions describing a problem that can't be reproduced and seemingly went away on its own (or went away when a typo was fixed) are off-topic as they are unlikely to help future readers."

Comment: The system won't let me close it anyway...

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question should work fine in an actual shell, but I can understand that some other program might not be able to parse it. Assuming we can't fix that program, a workaround might be to split the second part of the condition into a function:

```
cond2() { [[ "$x" = "z" ]] && cmd2; }
if cmd1 || cond2; then
     ...
```

That's not as brief, but if the parser is worth *anything*, it should be able to parse that function definition.